# What is /var/tmp/php-fpm ? This command is consuming high % of CPU

Tags: malware, cpu-load

Somebody kindly explain what kind of a file is `/var/tmp/php-fpm` and its uses? This command is consuming high CPU percentage when I checked using the `top` command. The file gets recreated even if I remove it.

[image: fpm-command]

Comment: Heh, that's almost definitely a cryptocurrency minor or something like that. You've been hacked.

Comment: Is there any possible solutions for this @muru ?

Comment: Oh, annoyingly I answered this since it was on the home page because I assumed it was a new question, but it was asked years ago and only modified today.

Comment: Removed the tag "php-fpm" which was added today as it's clear this question isn't about php-fpm and that indeed php-fpm is a fake name given to this malware to make it seem like it's part of php-fpm.

Answer (score 2):

`php-fpm` doesn't use `/var/tmp/php-fpm`, so what you are seeing is 99% some malware.

For a start you can:

- `kill` the process
- Delete the malware:

  ```
  sudo rm -rf /var/tmp/php-fpm
  ```
- Investigate what is going on and how this file got on your systems.

Answer (score 2):

The top process here is suspicious, because it is an executable running from `/var/tmp`, a location where proper system-level executables won't run from.  It's almost certainly malware.

There will be at least two parts to it - the executable itself, which you can find and delete fairly easily, and something that is executing it and possibly also recreating it.  This could be a startup script that runs when you log in (Linux has a variety of places these could be, but it will be somewhere in your home directory).  Or, an application on your system could be compromised or misconfigured into launching it.

The interesting thing here is you appear to also have genuine-looking `php-fpm` processes as well.  This may be why the malware one was given that name - to make it appear less suspicious.  If you are running genuine `php-fpm`, then you are running a web server, using PHP - possibly you have installed wordpress, or it could be some other software that runs a web interface and happens to use PHP.

It *could* be that the method the malware used to install itself is related to someone exploiting the web application you are running.  The fact that the malware is running as the `www-data` user is a strong clue that this is likely.

Or it could be that you followed instructions or a script that you found online that sneakily caused malware to be installed without you knowing, probably again somehow related to setting up your web application given that it's running as `www-data`.

Someone that is highly security conscious may be considering wiping and reinstalling the operating system at this point.  I don't know if you need to do that - it depends on whether you can determine how this malware got installed, because if you don't know, it could happen again.  This malware is running without particularly high priveleges on your system (`www-data` is lower privileges even than a regular user) but that doesn't mean it can't do bad things, like send spam or DDOS attacks from your computer, or figure out how to escalate its privileges at some future time.  Knowing that you're running something like this means you should take action to remove it and ensure it doesn't re-appear.